# atoi from char * returning 0 in C

Tags: c, atoi

Very new to C so please bear with me. I have a function that takes in 3 char * variables, `opcode`, `arg1` and `arg2`.

arg1 and arg2 can either be (1) a string containing the name of a variable holding an unsigned int, or (2) an actual integer.

Either way, I need to get the actual integer out. I am trying to use atoi so far but it seems to be returning 0 for the first case.

i.e.

`sscanf(instruction, "%s %s %s", opcode, arg1, arg2);`

`sum = atoi(arg1) + atoi(arg2);`

I can't post the entire code as it doesn't belong to me, but hopefully the above demonstration helps a little?

Comment: You should show some actual code, not try to describe it in English, which is significantly harder to express with the precision of C. It sounds as if you're expecting to retreieve the value of variable by name at run-time, which is something you cannot easily do in C.

Comment: Just added an example, but I'd rather avoid posting lots of code as it doesn't belong to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly for the first case you have arg as "var" and when you call `atoi("var")` you are expecting the value of `var` to be returned?

Comment: In the first case, is the name of variable, a name of variable in the same program?! Or is it a name in your input (for example if you are parsing another program)

Comment: It's the name of a variable in the same program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can't expect to retrieve the value of a named variable at run-time, in C. Variable names are not something that is kept when the code runs, then it's pure machine code and all variables have been "cooked down" to memory addresses. The names are no longer around.

The `atoi()` function converts a string holding an integer, such as `"4711"`, into the actual value, `4711`. That's all it does, it cannot retreive values "by name" in any way.

If you want to have a mechanism to map variable names to values when the program runs, you are going to have to *create* that mechanism yourself, since the language *does not have one*. For instance, you could create some kind of array of structures that let you associate names with values, but that would of course require you to initialize that array.

Something like this:

```
int foo = 12;
char *vname = "foo";

print("the value of %s is %d\n", vname, get_variable_value(vname));
```

simply *is not going to happen* in C, the function `get_variable_value()` *cannot exist*.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are used only at compile-time. Once the program is compiled, all information regarding what names you used are lost<sup>1</sup>. Therefore, you have no way of accessing a variable contents by a "string" containing its name at runtime.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> more precisely, they are available to the linker or possibly debugger, but that's not something you could use (or count on)

<sup>2</sup> I can think of a (terrible) way to do so with macros or use a map of all your variable names to their addresses, but I believe your program needs to be fixed by design.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a data structure in which you put the variables and the values of them. Look for "hash map" in the libraries that you use.

Then you can use `isdigit(arg[0])` to check whether the argument is a number or a variable name. Pseudocode:

```
sum = toInt(arg1) + toInt(arg2)

int toInt(char * arg) {
    return isdigit(arg[0]) ? atoi(arg) : map->lookupValue(arg);
}
```

Comment: This question is in C. `map->lookupValue(arg)` will not get `map` itself in the `lookupValue` function. Also, the question is not asking for variables in an input script, but the variables in the original program itself.

Comment: @Shahbaz - This answer is in C too! :) - I think the answer is a reasonable way to do a name->value mapping in *any* language. i.e. it looks like the kind of thing the OP should use, if that is what they are trying to achieve, don't you think?

Comment: I don't know where he might want to store `map`. Maybe a global variable is enough for his use case. Or he can move this code into the `lookupValue()` method of the `map` and pass that around. Or maybe he already has a context structure which he passed into most methods.